# how to display WPF window from a server?

Tags: html, wpf

I'm trying to create a canvas, but I don't want to use HTML5 because it is client-based which makes my js code accessible easily. I also don't want to use blazor, because I'm still within the html5 canvas boundaries.
I'm thinking of WPF because it has fire power when creating canvas and its code naturally hidden in dll.
I don't want to distribute it via exe because that will make it copiable and shareable and lots of work to secure it.

I understand that WPF may soon die and may involve cost, but I'm OK with that risk. I saw many links about incorporating web browser inside WPF but what I want is the opposite (if possible) to display WPF in either a window or a browser coming for the server. And customers will interact with that or though a mediary. Is there a kind of technology that will allow me to show a window in my server that has a desktop application in it like WPF?

Is that possible at all?